# NLA animations aren't combining

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I have two animations, one that makes my object bob up and down, and another one that moves it around. I have given both of these a fake user (shield icon) and have pushed them down to the nla animation area. I have also created another track with add<add track (nla window). I have set both of their blend modes to "combine" and for some reason my object stays at it's original place when I imported it.

[image: my nla setup]

I have done something like this but the hovering animation gets overriden by the driving one. How can I get them to play together?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of you NLA setup or are you able to share your Blend file with just the nla and animation?

Comment: make sure that you're tweaking the parameters of the Strip panel (Strip tab of the N panel)

Comment: Yes, I'm in the strip panel

Comment: @DarkSoul I put a screenshot

Comment: Judging from the screenshot it is because the strip needs to be longer than the bottom one. It needs to cover the area you want to animate if that makes sense.

Comment: Nope, I repeated the animation and it's still not working @DarkSoul

Comment: Okay but you need to explain your problem in more detail if you want anyone to help. You could also share your blend file to make it easier. What exactly isn't working? And what do both animation strips do? What are you trying to archieve and where what happens right now?

Comment: @DarkSoul Ok, so when I set the driving animation to replace, it works as expected. But when I add a hover animation above it with combine, the driving animation still gets applied but the object appears really far away. So what I want to happen is I want the driving animation to get combined with the hover animation, and for it to hover while it's following the driving animation.

Comment: So your driving animation moves an object and you want to add an hover animation on top to make it hover? If you add the hover strip on top, your object appears very far? In that case it sounds like adding the hover strip on top changes the location values of your object. Does your strip by chance animate the same values? In that case it can give unwanted results. I really suggest to upload your blend to have a closer look. Create a backup and remove everyting in it except the object and animation.

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... make it simple as possible, delete useless elements for example